# How to reduce a healthlevel by 1 when a button is clicked in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

I'm starting out with kotlin. and I'm having trouble understanding OnClickListener. Here After setting the initial health level to 10, I need to reduce the health level by 1 and display it. So far I have initiliased the healthlevel and set the onclick, but How do declare the function to reduce it by 1 and call it when the button is clicked?

```
val TAG = "MyMessage"

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    Log.i("LIFECYCLE", "OnCreate")
}

private var healthLevel: Int = 10 //Set the initial health level to 10
private lateinit var healthLevelTextView: TextView
private lateinit var sneezeBtn: Button
private lateinit var takeMedicationButton: Button
private lateinit var blowNoseButton: Button

override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
    outState.putInt("Answer", healthLevel)
    Log.i(TAG, "Called SaveInstanceState()")
}

sneezeBtn.setOnClickListener{ _ ->
    // the function goes here 
}
```

Comment: This is the best beginner app I've seen :D blow that nose!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vitor has the answer, but just as a couple of alternatives...

You might want to create a function to update *and* display your value together:

```
fun setHealth(health: Int) {
    healthLevel = health
    healthLevelTextView.text = healthLevel
}
```

That couples the update with the display change, so the two things always happen together. And if you always set `healthLevel` with this function (instead of setting the variable directly), the display and value will always be in sync

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    // set your view variables, so the TextView is ready to update
    setHealth(INITIAL_HEALTH_VALUE)
```

And if you like, Kotlin [lets us put a setter function on the variable itself](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html)

```
var healthLevel: Int = 10
    set(value) {
        field = value
        healthLevelTextView.text = health
    }
```

so every time you change the value of `healthLevel`, it also updates the display. You can use the `observable` delegate too

```
var healthLevel: Int by Delegates.observable(10) { _, oldValue, newValue ->
    healthLevelTextView.text = newValue
}
```

These are more advanced than just setting the value and updating the view yourself, just pointing out that they exist as alternatives and ways to keep your logic in one place. Also with these examples, they only run the code after you *first set a value* - they have a default of 10 in both cases, but initialising that default won't run the setter code or the observable function. So you'd still need to go `healthLevel = 10` to get the text to display the initial value.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your `healthLevel` variable by using:

```
sneezeBtn.setOnClickListener {
    healthLevel--
    healthLevelTextView.setText(healthLevel.toString())
}
```

As a side note, if you use `lateinit` you lose one of the best features of Kotlin, which is Null Safety. If you don't know how to use that yet, I recommend you to start learning it as soon as possible.

You can also use a very nice feature of Android with kotlin, where the objects for your views are generated automatically in your Activity, you just have to type your XML views id, instead of having to use `findViewById` everywhere.

Comment: How does `lateinit` lose null safety? It’s appropriate for variables that will be initialized at the first entry point of the class (`onCreate`) and allows you to avoid needless use of nullability. That’s still null safety and is preferred to using nullable variables in most cases. The feature you mentioned at the end is called synthetic view references, and has been superseded by the safer view-binding feature.

Comment: `lateinit` does not actually lose `null-safety` but opens up a caveat of crashes due to `lateinit property XYZ not initialized` so you have to "null-guard" it with `if (::someLateinitProperty.isInitialized) { /* work with it */ }`

Comment: Ideally you'll only use ``lateinit`` where you can guarantee the property will be initialised before you access it (and a crash is fine because it means your code needs fixing). But even in the situations where you *do* need to check it's initialised, it should only be in a few places (say in a singleton ``getInstance()`` scenario). Making something nullable means it has to be checked everywhere it's accessed, which is way more of a burden. And if your code structure means you need to do that with a ``lateinit`` variable, you should probably be making it nullable instead anyway!

Comment: I should also say that imo using ``lateinit`` for view variables you're going to instantiate immediately in ``onCreate`` is an ideal use case for them. Those first lifecycle callbacks are where an ``Activity`` really gets initialised, and ``lateinit`` allows you to defer that stuff so it doesn't have to be done in the constructor/init block (which isn't really a useful place to do things in an activity)

Comment: I didn't know synthetic view references has been superseded, so thank you @Tenfour04, but I did know how it is called and I left it out because it looks like Henil is beginning and I wanted my answer to be as understandable as possible.

Comment: @cactustictacs About using lateinit for views, I don't think it's a good use case, since findViewById itself is annotated with Nullable, and handling null safety in this case is not that hard.

Comment: @Shark Not if you initialize in `onCreate()`

Comment: @VitorRamos the `View`'s variable isn't nullable though - because it's expected to be there, and ``findViewById`` should crash if it isn't (because you've done something wrong with your layout and you need to know about it). Making the view nullable when it's never null just makes your code more complex for no reason, it can spiral out into the rest of your codebase (people having to wrangle a nullable that's never actually going to be null), and in this case it hides an error (a missing view). ``lateinit`` avoids all of that - it's just delaying initialisation in a safe way!

Answer (score 0):

I assume, your code sample is within an Activity class and you have a layout file `activity_main.xml` which looks something like this:

```xml
    ...
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/healthLevelTextViewId"
            ...
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/sneezeBtnId"
            ...
            />
    ...
```

This would be the code with your desired functionality:

```kotlin
class YourActivity : Activity {

    private var healthLevel: Int = 10

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        
        // retrieve references to the text view and button
        val healthLevelTextView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.healthLevelTextViewId)
        val sneezeBtn = findViewById<Button>(R.id.sneezeBtnId)

        // the OnClickListener must be initialized within a method body, as it is not a method itself.
        sneezeBtn.setOnClickListener { _ ->
            // implementation from the answer from Vitor Ramos
            healthLevel--
            healthLevelTextView.setText(healthLevel.toString())
        }
    }
}
```

You can further improve the code:

- Add `apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'` to your app's `build.gradle` file. Then you can reference your views directly using their IDs. So instead of

  ```kotlin
      val sneezeBtn = findViewById<Button>(R.id.sneezeBtnId)
      sneezeBtn.setOnClickListener { ... }
  ```

  you can use the Id directly like this:

  ```kotlin
      sneezeBtnId.setOnClickListener { ... }
  ```

  AndroidStudio will give you a hint to add an import for `sneezeBtnId`.
- Use [View Models](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel), [LiveData](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata) and [Data Binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding). This is the recommended, but a little bit more advanced technique.